# remove value from end of string vba

Tags: string, excel, numbers, move, vba

This will be pretty simple for those versed in vba - I write it so rarely that I need a lot of help. I've seen a heap of threads and tutorials about manipulating strings, but none seem to capture what I'm attempting to do, working in excel, which is simply this:

- remove the numbers from the end of the string, then move them to another cell.

e.g. "april 26 april 27 merchant 23.78" The goal is to take 23.78 out of the string and move it to an adjacent cell.

Simple enough, but there are string characteristics (problems) that I have not been able to solve:

- target number is variable
- target number length is variable
- there are multiple numbers in the string, but only the numbers at the end (right) are targeted

Certainties

- The target numbers are always at the end (right)
- the target numbers are always separated from the rest of the string by a space

I'm thinking that a substring function that moves through characters from right to left and stops when a character is not a number (i.e. a space or a letter) might work well.
Any suggestions the forum might have on writing such a query would be most helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi there's a nice function "Instrrev" which is like Instr but searches from the right hand side... so you can use that to find the first " " space character from the right:

```
intLastSpace = instrrev(stString, " ")
```

Then just a case of using `Left(stString, intLastSpace - 1)`

[EDIT: To address comment]

Something like...

```
Sub SplitStuff()
    Dim rgList As Range
    Dim rgCell As Range
    Dim intSpace As Integer

    Set rgList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Whatever").Range("A1:A200")

    For Each rgCell In rgList
        intSpace = InStrRev(rgCell.Value, " ")
        rgCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(rgCell.Value, intSpace + 1)
        rgCell.Value = Left(rgCell.Value, intSpace - 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Im having trouble figuring out how to use the function you suggested. I don't know how to get the function to take the values at the right and move them over, maybe something like 

 
`Sub ValCut()
Dim rngA As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim r As Range, rows As Long
    Dim intLastSpace as String
    intLastSpace = InstrRev(stString, " ")

    Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A100")
    For Each cell In rngA
        Left(stString, intLastSpace -1)
           intLastSpace.Offset(0, 1)
    Next cell
End Sub`

Comment: You were nearly there :) See above: have edited answer

Comment: Thanks for help, it finally works, and I would have been lost without your assistance. 
One note - there was a runtime error (5) on the line:


`rgCell.value = Left(rgCell.Value, intSpace - 1)`


 but I noticed that the code still grabbed the number and moved it, but couldn't proceed to next due to the error. I removed the line, and it works fine.

What was the purpose of that line?

Comment: So if original rgCell.value = "PartA PartB" then rgCell.offset(0,1) is set to PartB, and then the original rgCell.value is set to "PartA" (i.e. PartB removed) 

It shouldn't have thrown an error unless perhaps you have some values with no space at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2013, you can do this without VBA too. Just start typing what you want (23.78) in the next column and do one more example too. A new feature called Flash Fill will then fill down the rest of the column automatically for you.

In older versions of Excel, you can use Data - Text to Columns - Delimited - by a space.

Comment: I'm using 2011 on a mac, and flash fill gives me weird values. I tried the text to columns approach initially - it works great if the strings have equal numbers of spaces. The string length is variable, as is the number of spaces, so the target values end up in different columns.